# Issue with generating a SSL protected web

Tags: authentication, ssl

Is there a simple way to generate a SSL protected web, I followed this [description](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html) i found it a bite complicated for a beginner.

I also when i get to I try `sudo sh -c "echo '01' > /etc/ssl/CA/serial"`  I get `sudo: unable to resolve host euca-192-1-1-1: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: Are you trying to run a web host or other service with SSL encryption, or are you trying to actually set up your own Certificate Authority?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I am trying to set up a Self-Signed Certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is generate a self-signed certificate, you don't even need to get into the creation or acceptance of a Certificate Authority.  From the site you have linked in your question, you need only to follow the following sections:

- Generating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
- Creating a Self-Signed Certificate
- Installing the Certificate

## Generating the Signing Request:

The following command will create a key file which be used as the basis for everything that follows:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
```

Keep this key secret and safe.  Never send it anywhere; only use it internally to generate *other* things which will be publicized.

To generate the actual certificate signing request using the freshly-generated key:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

## Generating the Certificate

Take the `key` and `csr` files from the previous step, and run them through the following command to generate the actual certificate (the `crt` file):

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

You can then take the `key` and `crt` files and roll them into whatever application you're wishing to apply the self-signed certificate to.